# What is the right way to update a custom timer job?

Tags: timer-jobs

I created a custom timer job (SharePoint 2010) which gets registered through a feature receiver. At the moment the custom timer job works fine but I need to make changes to the code. So, naturally I recompiled my project and repackaged it into a WSP.

However, when I run `update-spsolution` the timerjob continues to run the old code. I have verified the the assembly is deployed successfully. So other parts of the site have been updated as a result but the timerjob continues to behave as before.

I also tried restarting IIS but that did not help. I then deactivated/reactivated the feature, but still the timerjob executes old code.

How can I update this timer job properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The timer job is run by SharePoint Timer Service (OWSTimer.exe). So you need to restart the service (so that the new dll is referenced) from the *Services* control panel.

To open Services, Start>Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Services. Right-click the SharePoint Timer Service and click Restart.

Comment: A life saver... been struggling to resolve the mistery why my job doesnt execute the recompiled version. Also I noticed after receiving the list it start to throw error message to MS Event Viewer saying the list is no longer available when in fact it was never been use after recompilation. Thanks.

Comment: So glad I found this answer!  Totally fixed weird null references I was seeing while debugging!