# What's the right way to get an SPWebApplication reference in WebApplication scoped custom timer job?

Tags: 2010, custom-timer-job

I have created a custom timer job.  I deploy it with a feature that has a WebApplication scope.  The Execute() method in my job definition class keeps throwing errors.  I'm trying to get a reference to the Web Application in the Execute method, but nothing seems to work.  I've tried several methods of getting this reference:

```
SPWebApplication webapp = this.WebApplication;
```

and

```
SPWebApplication webapp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
```

both of these are returning null.

Any clues what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the Sharepoint Timer Service fixed my issue:

Start>Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Services>SharePoint 2010 Timer

ref: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/22466/17398